# @font-face can't work on chrome and safari of mac os

Tags: reactjs, sass

On chrome, safari of MacBook pro, the font of my web app is "Baloo 2", cursive. But on macOS, in safari and chrome, the font is cursive. How can I make the @font-face work on the chrome and safari of mac?

font link from google fonts: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Baloo+2

```
File: font.scss 
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Baloo 2', cursive;
    src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+2&display=swap');
}

File variable.scss
$font-Baloo:'Baloo 2', cursive;

File comman.scss
.font-family-baloo {
    font-family:$font-Baloo;
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the `url` you're providing, it should be `https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/baloo2/v12/wXK0E3kTposypRydzVT08TS3JnAmtdgazZpp_led7Q.woff2`. But to be honnest, I would use the import rule `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+2&display=swap');
`

Comment: Okay, I will use @import method